# why is scr path without . / if they are in the same directory?

Tags: node.js, relative-path, src

I've learnt what absolute path and relative path are:

- ./  refers to current path
- ../ refers to parent path
- / refers to root path

I'm confused why when it is 'src', and ./ is not needed if file A uses file B, and they are in the same directory:

[image: IDE screenshot of hello.html]

But if in node.js, `fs.readFile`, I need to add ./ in the path parameter, they are in the same directory:

[image: IDE screenshot of 05-03-template.js]

I've searched Stack Overflow but I didn't find a similar question. Sorry, if I didn't use the right keywords.

Comment: The main reason is the that nodejs and browser doesn't work the same way. As default, in nodejs if you are reading a file without `./` it's gonna check `node_modules` file for that thing you are looking for but browser directly looking same directory so. But in any case you can use `./` inside browser and nodejs, which is a good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, but `./path` and `path` it's the same with the same results.

But, you should always use `./path`

[More info](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems me that I've a stupid question. Previously I added ./ to path in src, but it didn't work. Now I try again, it works.